# make check fails after building gpgme

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, configure, gnupg, gpgme

I am trying to build gpgme-1.3.2 on an Ubuntu 12.04. I've already built libgpg-error-1.10 and libassuan-2.0.3. The commands were simply:

```
./configure && make && make check && sudo make install
```

Both libraries built succesful and `make check` gave me no fails.

However `make check` on my gpgme built gave me 22 of 22 failing checks, although there were no built errors. I used the same command I used for building the other two libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I came up with, was setting the `prefix` and `libexecdir` of configure as following:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib
```

According to the [gnu make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html) prefix tells `make` in which folder the folders are where it should put the resulting binaries. The libexecdir option tells it where to put executables not to be run by users but by programs (in other words: libraries).

The cause of the error was libgpg-error not being where libassuan and libgpg expected it. This [post](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3a-gpgme-android-build-fails-looking-for--usr-local-lib-libgpg-error.la-p33473702.html) claims that setting the prefix, set the correct path in gpg-error-config. By using this path gpgme was able to find libgpg-error and the checks worked.